# Should a mysql slave answer queries much slower then the master?

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.3

I am seeing a slight issue on a mysql slave server, or at least on the surface it appears there might be an issue.

Both mysql's are virtual machines

The master and slave are the same OS (debian10) and the sql's are the same version, 10.3.27, and were installed installed only half-hour apart.

The replication itself works great, and most writes to the slave appear within seconds including new db's, changed data etc.

I have run a few tests recently, where I change some wordpress config's to point at the ip of the slave instead of the master so I can feel a bit more comfortable all is working well with replication and as a disaster recovery test.

The problem is any sites utilizing the slave for sql data are horribly slow, and as soon as I change the ip back to the master speed returns.

Keep in mind, in this scenario the web server never changes.

In this scenario, NEITHER sql server touches the internet as the public cards are disabled on both master and slave.

Both sql servers have absolutely nothing else installed on them and are stock Debian, maria and webmin.

Private traffic and public traffic are on different subnets and different vlans in the switch so completely segmented. (untagged)

I have tried moving the virtual machine to different hosts and it does not have any effect.

I have tried clearing the web server cache and even restarting the web server.

Ping times to the ip's of each sql server are identical at 1ms or less.

Both have identical firewall rules, and tests where firewall is disabled there is no change.

Before anyone suggests switch ports, this also happens even when both VM's are on the same physical host, so the PRIVATE traffic would be going in and out the same NIC's and traversing the same port on the switch.

I have not enabled any automatic failover, but before I even begin to think about that I would like to see this issue resolved. We are talking of cases where a small site that may take a few seconds to load on the master suddenly taking 10 to 20 or even 30 seconds for a page load.

Now I understand a slave is not exactly designed for the reads, but is it normal for a slave to be a half minute slower on the query then the master?

I have done a bit of searching and have yet to see anyone talk about this, but most query's on the subject start talking about the replication traffic itself being slow, or the time factor for the slave to catch up from the replication log files etc from the master, but none of that is the case, replication itself is pretty darn close to instant.

I hope I explained the situation clearly and if anyone has things to try let me know.

Universal4

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO offers help in database config questions like this one!

Comment: are you asking for MySQL or sql server ?

Comment: Compare the MariaDB configuration on both servers. Also enabled the slow query log [with explain enabled](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/explain-in-the-slow-query-log/). Ensure that `long_query_time` is < 1 second. Compare the slow queries in the log to `explain {query}` on the faster server.

Comment: also check `skip-name-resolve` is part of the configuration. It could be a reverse DNS lookup time of the web server from the slower slave server.

Comment: Well since the websites look at the mysql servers by IP Address, DNS would not involved I would think and the only thing that changes between the two servers is the last octec, but I will look at both servers to see what the setting for that.

I will look into the suggestion to enable the explain in the log to see if that points to anything that seems to help.

Comment: Thank you everyone who jumped in with suggestions, it ended up being skip-name-resolve. This was an immediate fix.

Comment: Congratulations.  Welcome to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Speed up postmeta via:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta